# android.content.ContentResolver.query NoSuchMethodError

Tags: android

I am getting android.content.ContentResolver.query NoSuchMethodError on a few devices in production, which report they are running Android 4.0.4.  Has there been a change to the android.content.ContentResolver.query that I am not aware of ?  I haven't been able to locate anything in the android docs that would indicate the query method on ContentResolver would be missing on a 4.0.4 device.

Comment: Getting the exact same error for 4.0.4. Strange!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out

```
query (Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder, CancellationSignal cancellationSignal)
```

was introduced in API 16

while

```
query (Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder)
```

was there since API 1